# Use numpy where on a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional array similar to the following and i'm trying to delete the strings that end with * (stars) such that I can convert it into an array of floats.

```
    array1 = np.column_stack((a, b, c, d)) 
    array1 = np.array([
       ['*0.70*', '21.59', '4.37', '21.70'],
       ['2.15', '21.42', '5.63', '22.33'],
       ['*8.00*', '21.17', '5.11', '22.40'],
       ['2.36', '22.88', '*2.54*', '*20.95*'],
       ['2.07', '22.64', '6.68', '22.26']
       ])
```

**Is there a way to us np.where to give the coordinate within the array of the valuse highlighted with stars, and not just index so I can delete the entire row?**

So Ideal output would be somthing along the lines ofK

```
fil1 = np.where(np.char.endswith(array1, "*") == True)

print(fil1) 
(0,0), (0,2), (2, 3), (3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.where` returns 1 array per dimension. If you want to know the indices of the rows containing stars, just do:

```
starred_rows = np.unique(np.where(np.char.endswith(array1, "*") == True)[0])
```

To get the index pairs, you can use zip:

```
np.array(list(zip(*np.where(np.char.endswith(array1, "*") == True))))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Ideal output mentioned above you need to use zip

```
fil1 = list(zip(*np.where(np.char.endswith(array1, "*") == True)))
print(fil1)  
[(0, 0), (2, 0), (3, 2), (3, 3)] //result
```

If you want to get only the index of rows, you can take the unique of the first element of the your result.

```
fil1 = list(set(np.where(np.char.endswith(array1, "*") == True)[0]))
print(fil1)
[0, 2, 3]  // result
```

Comment: `np.transpose(np.where(...))` or `np.argwhere(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [81]: array1 = np.array([ 
    ...:        ['*0.70*', '21.59', '4.37', '21.70'], 
    ...:        ['2.15', '21.42', '5.63', '22.33'], 
    ...:        ['*8.00*', '21.17', '5.11', '22.40'], 
    ...:        ['2.36', '22.88', '*2.54*', '*20.95*'], 
    ...:        ['2.07', '22.64', '6.68', '22.26'] 
    ...:        ])
```

The `char` test returns a boolean array:

```
In [84]: mask = np.char.endswith(array1,"*")                                             
In [85]: mask                                                                            
Out[85]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

`np.nonzero` (aka `np.where`) finds the coordinates of the `True` values, one array per dimension:

```
In [86]: np.nonzero(mask)                                                                
Out[86]: (array([0, 2, 3, 3]), array([0, 0, 2, 3]))
```

If you want to delete the rows, the first array can be used (duplicate 3 apparently doesn't bother `delete`):

```
In [88]: np.delete(array1, np.nonzero(mask)[0], 0)                                       
Out[88]: 
array([['2.15', '21.42', '5.63', '22.33'],
       ['2.07', '22.64', '6.68', '22.26']], dtype='<U7')
```

But we can also find rows with any True with:

```
In [89]: mask.any(axis=1)                                                                
Out[89]: array([ True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

and use that to select those rows (boolean array indexing)

```
In [91]: array1[mask.any(axis=1)]                                                        
Out[91]: 
array([['*0.70*', '21.59', '4.37', '21.70'],
       ['*8.00*', '21.17', '5.11', '22.40'],
       ['2.36', '22.88', '*2.54*', '*20.95*']], dtype='<U7')
```

or select their `not`:

```
In [92]: array1[~mask.any(axis=1)]                                                       
Out[92]: 
array([['2.15', '21.42', '5.63', '22.33'],
       ['2.07', '22.64', '6.68', '22.26']], dtype='<U7')
```

`np.nonzero(Out[89])` is                                                          `(array([0, 2, 3]),)`, the desired delete rows.

Other answers have used the Python list version of transpose; `numpy's` own transpose works as well:

```
In [93]: np.argwhere(mask)                                                               
Out[93]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3]])
In [94]: np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))                                                  
Out[94]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

For the purpose of deleting rows this transpose isn't any more useful than the `where`.